# ASP.NET ScriptManager not setting history points?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager, browser-history

I have an Ajax enabled website, with some calls to the Script Manager to set history points like so:

```
if (uxScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
{
   uxScriptManager.AddHistoryPoint("x", taxid.ToString());
}
```

This works just fine 90% of the time.

However, about 10% of the time, the history points stop being set. This seems to happen when I've clicked around a bit and then start using the back button to go back pretty far (usually 6 or 7 steps in the history).

Has anyone else noticed/seen this behavior? The code I've got that picks up the state information from the history points to rebuild the page seems to work fine.It's just sometimes the script manager seems to forget to set the history point.

**EDIT**

I've noticed some strange behavior with the script manager - after the third or the fourth click back, is seems to break and the Ajax calls no longer work. The user needs to reload the page in order for the history to start working again. Anyone seen this type of behavior? (I'd think if I wasn't doing it right, it wouldn't work at all...)